# Doubling each letter in a String

Tags: java, while-loop, char

I'm doing a project for Java 1, and I'm completely stuck on this question.

Basically I need to double each letter in a string.

```
"abc"  ->  "aabbcc"
"uk"   ->  "uukk"
"t"    ->  "tt"
```

I need to do it in a while loop in what is considered "Java 1" worthy.  So i'm guessing that this means more of a problematic approach.

I know that the easiest way for me to do this, from my knowledge, would be using the charAt method in a while loop, but for some reason my mind can't figure out how to return the characters to another method as a string.

Thanks

[EDIT] My Code (wrong, but maybe this will help)

```
int index = 0;
  int length = str.length();
  while (index < length) {
      return str.charAt(index) + str.charAt(index);
      index++;
  }
```

Comment: Have a look at `StringBuilder`, and see if that helps you. I'd use a `for` loop rather than a `while` loop though.

Comment: have you written any code to approach this problem?

Comment: Seriously Java 1? Why? Where do you get that?

Comment: @RaviKumar, yes actually.  I believe my "logic" is correct, it's an actual approach that I can't seem to get.  I'll add it in the question if that helps.

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj Seriously Java 1 what?  It's a High School class.

Comment: taylortdhouse: From the context I assumed that you're talking about first java release(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#JDK_1.0_.28January_23.2C_1996.29). I don't see how name of the class you're taking is relevant.

Comment: The "index++" line will NEVER be executed. When the compiler returns something, it does not execute the remaining code.

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj I mentioned it because I didn't want some crazy solution that I didn't understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, a for loop would really make more sense here, but if you need to use a while loop then it would look like this:

```
String s = "abc";
String result = "";
int i = 0;
while (i < s.length()){
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    result = result + c + c;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks for using a while loop like I asked!  I completely forgot that you can change the value of variables during the loop :)

Answer (score 11):

```
String s="mystring".replaceAll(".", "$0$0");
```

The method [`String.replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) uses the regular expression syntax which is described in the [documentation of the `Pattern` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/regex/Pattern.html), where we can learn that `.` matches “any character”. Within the replacement, *$number* refers to numbered “capturing group” whereas `$0` is predefined as the entire match. So `$0$0` refers to the matching character two times. As the name of the method suggests, it is performed for all matches, i.e. all characters.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
public void doubleString(String input) {

    String output = "";

    for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
        output += c + c;
    }

    System.out.println(output);

}
```

Comment: If you input is a word e.g. "hello" then the output would be "208202216216222". This is not intended i guess.

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition is very good. `charAt(i)` will return the character in the string at location `i`, yes?

You also said you wanted to use a loop. A `for` loop, traversing the length of the list, `string.length()`, will allow you to do this. At every single node in the string, what do you need to do? Double the character.

Let's take a look at your code:

```
int index = 0;
int length = str.length();
while (index < length) {
    return str.charAt(index) + str.charAt(index);    //return ends the method
    index++;
}
```

Problematically for your code, you are returning two characters immediately upon entering the loop. So for a string `abc`, you are returning `aa`. Let's store the `aa` in memory instead, and then return the completed string like so:

```
int index = 0;
int length = str.length();
String newString = "";
while (index < length) {
    newString += str.charAt(index) + str.charAt(index);
    index++;
}
return newString;
```

This will add the character to `newString`, allowing you to return the entire completed string, as opposed to a single set of doubled characters.

By the way, this may be easier to do as a for loop, condensing and clarifying your code. My personal solution (for a Java 1 class) would look something like this:

```
String newString = "";
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
    newString += str.charAt(i) + str.charAt(i);
}
return newString;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    String a = "abcd";
    char[] aa = new char[a.length() * 2];
    for(int i = 0, j = 0; j< a.length(); i+=2, j++){
        aa[i] = a.charAt(j);
        aa[i+1]= a.charAt(j);
    }
    System.out.println(aa);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static char[] doubleChars(final char[] input) {
    final char[] output = new char[input.length * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        output[i] = input[i];
        output[i + 1] = input[i];
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is inside a method, you should understand that you can only **return once** from a method. After encountering a return statement, the control goes back to the **calling method**. Thus your approach of returning char every time in a loop is faulty.

```
int index = 0;
int length = str.length();
while (index < length) {
   return str.charAt(index) + str.charAt(index); // only the first return is reachable,other are not executed
   index++;
 }
```

Change your method to build a String and return it

```
public String modify(String str)
{
    int index = 0;
    int length = str.length();
    String result="";
    while (index < length) {
       result += str.charAt[index]+str.charAt[index];
       index++;
    }
    return result;
}
```